# If condition not matching inside a foreach loop in perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to match a string with if statement inside a foreach loop but its not matching although i get the same string with printed before if statement inside foreach loop. Please help.

```
use Net::Telnet;
$ip='xx.xxx.xx.xx';
$ip_port='10002';
$port  = new Net::Telnet->new( Host=>$ip,Port=>$ip_port,Dump_log=> "dump.log");

my @folder= $port->cmd("ls");
sleep(2);

$folders=@folder;
print "Number of folders are:$folders\n";

foreach my $folder(@folder)
{
        print "Folder before if is:$folder\n";
        if(($folder eq "acc") || ($folder eq "bda"))
    {

       # some code here.
    }
}
```

Comment: what is @folder after the ls?  show output of `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper \@folder;`

Comment: I strongly suspect that white space is your enemy here:

Comment: Output showing as: $VAR1 = [
          "ls\r\r\n",
          "acc\r\n",
          "bda\r\n",
          "root\@android:/mnt/sdcard "
        ];
Number of folders are:4

Comment: Got it! I just added this before if statement: $folder =~ s/\r|\n//g;

Comment: But the "ls" and "root\@android:/mnt/sdcard" are not folders. How do i remove them? Please help.

Comment: You can always use `shift` and `pop` to remove the first and last elements of an array, if you know the ends of the array will always have lines you want to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Your strings probably contain white space. You can use something like *chomp* to remove it, or alternatively use regexs.

Try:

```
if ($folder =~ /^(acc|bda)/) {
    # some code here
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this match the folder names "accumulate" and "bday", too? `chomp`ing is a good suggestion here!

Comment: `chomp` is what I first thought, but if you have a mix of newline styles between systems (ie. DOS-style `\r\n` coming to a Linux box), it's sometimes more effective to clean that up with `s/[\r\n]//g`.